# Downloaded symbol files for WinDbg.exe do not load

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols

I installed retail symbols in D:\Symbols and given the path to my windbg.exe but it can't be loaded why?

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Connected to Windows 7 7601 x64 target at (Sat Jan 31 14:38:56.920 2015 (UTC + 3:30)), ptr64 TRUE
Symbol search path is: D:\Symbols
Executable search path is: 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntkrnlmp.exe - 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.18247.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02c4b000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`02e8e6d0
Debug session time: Sat Jan 31 14:38:56.968 2015 (UTC + 3:30)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:43:25.215
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Debug Symbols that Microsoft provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028) are only usable for the RTM or Sp1 Version of Windows 7. When you install an Update, the PDBs no longer match.

Here you must [point to the Symbol Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) to download the new PDBs:

```
SRV*D:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easier if you have an internet connection to let windbg find and download the correct ones for you, whereby it will be cached locally:

`.symfix;.reload`

Will go and fetch the correct symbols from the MS symbol server at `http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

if you download them yourself then you have to download the correct version matching your specific build and this is just too much of a headache to maintain so IMO it's just simpler to just let windbg handle this for you.